# Spring Cloud Starter Eureka Setup

Tags: spring-cloud, spring-cloud-netflix

I try to setup Spring Cloud Eureka by following [a tutorial link](https://spring.io/blog/2015/01/20/microservice-registration-and-discovery-with-spring-cloud-and-netflix-s-eureka) on Spring.io. I get the server up, but not its client. The tutorial uses Spring Boot 1.5.9.RELEASE. But there isn't the version of Spring Cloud Starter Eureka on http://mvnrepository.com/. So, I try 1.4.0 and 2.0.0.M2. I get

```
09:15:41.027 [main] ERROR org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication - Application startup failed
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 
org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder.<init>([Ljava/lang/Class;)V
    at org.springframework.cloud.bootstrap.BootstrapApplicationListener.bootstrapServiceContext(BootstrapApplicationListener.java:166)
    at org.springframework.cloud.bootstrap.BootstrapApplicationListener.onApplicationEvent(BootstrapApplicationListener.java:104)
    at org.springframework.cloud.bootstrap.BootstrapApplicationListener.onApplicationEvent(BootstrapApplicationListener.java:70)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.doInvokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:172)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.invokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:165)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:139)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:122)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.event.EventPublishingRunListener.environmentPrepared(EventPublishingRunListener.java:74)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.environmentPrepared(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:54)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.prepareEnvironment(SpringApplication.java:325)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:296)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1118)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1107)
    at com.example.gateway.GatewayApplication.main(GatewayApplication.java:30)
```

What do I do wrong?

I use Gradle for the build tool.

Answer (score 3):

The artifact has been renamed to `spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-client` for Spring Cloud Finchley and Spring Boot 2

Comment: I am aware the renaming and I have tried the new version. The renaming isn't the only change of the package. It behaves quite differently to my experience for Spring Boot 2 (both M7 and snapshot). With a command "mvn package", I get an error: "com.sun.jersey.api.client.ClientHandlerException: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect". It even doesn't go the far with Gradle. I try to file a bug report. But Spring Cloud isn't listed on the Spring Jira site.

Comment: Spring Boot 1.5.x is not compatible with Finchley. Spring Boot 2 is compatible with Finchley.

Comment: Spring Cloud uses GitHub issues

Comment: Accroding to this online document https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-netflix/ , the latest version is '2.0.0.M5'. But I get unable to find the version  of spring-cloud-starter-eureka.

Comment: It doesn't exist. See my answer. It was renamed

Comment: Checkout the [release notes](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-cloud/wiki/Spring-Cloud-Edgware-Release-Notes) for a list of name changes